# Login system store sessions in database

Tags: php, session, authentication

**What am I making?**

I am developing a login system for my own website, when people login a session_token is generated, and saved using PHP sessions.
The generated session_token will also be inserted to a database table, along with the logged in user's id, and session_expire datetime.

Every time the user returns to my website, it checks if the session_token exists and has not expired, in the sessions database table.

**Question**

How can I prevent my sessions table from getting full of expired session_tokens? I don't want to run a cron_job to remove expired sessions every x minutes.

Comment: Make the user's `id` a `UNIQUE KEY` in your database table. Then when the `session_token` is expired and you create a new `session_token` you update that user's row. Then you will only have 1 row per user.

Comment: My purpose is to have multiple sessions per user, since I have accounts that are being used by more than 1 person at a time.

Comment: Do you want to avoid cron altogether, or are you just concerned about it running frequently? How quickly will this table fill up? Seems like every few minutes could be overkill for frequency of a cron job for this purpose.

Comment: As an option use storage that does eviction itself and/or has TTL as a parameter (memcache[d], redis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a cron job, you can use the [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html), or when you go to check and see if a token is expired or not, you can remove it if it is already expired.

Comment: You mean every time any session is being checked, execute a query to remove expired sessions?

Comment: Since you don't want to use a cron job, that is probably the best way to go about it. Whenever you check to see if the current is valid, check to see if you have any others that are expired. However if this operation runs a lot you will find that it may slow your script down more than if you were just to use a cron job every X minutes/seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Ill be looking further for any options, but you answered part of my question.